# I'm not able to have just the admin's information display in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Ruby 2.2, Rails 4.2.5.1, with Devise gem. I defined the user as admin when installing Devise. Each admin can create an event. When logged in, I want the admin to only see the list of events they have created.  At this point all events created by all admins are showing up. Having tried many solutions offered in my searches, I continue to get various errors so I have put the code back to working order but, again, I'm getting all events showing up. I'm considering installing CanCanCan as I understand its Ability function might help, but this is such a common need I feel there has to be an easy approach I'm missing.  Any help would be most appreciated.  Below is the events controller, events views index.html.erb, the events model and admin model, and the routes.rb code.

events_controller.rb:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

def index
   @events = Event.all
end

def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @event = Event.new
end

def edit
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)

  if @event.save
    redirect_to @event
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def update
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])

  if @event.update(event_params)
    redirect_to @event
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event.destroy

  redirect_to events_path
end

private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name_of_event, :description_tag_line, :description, :date, :time, :location, :ticket_price)
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admins
    resources :events
      resources :ticket_buyers

  get 'pages/home'

  get 'pages/about'

  root 'home#index'

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
end
```

model event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :admin

    has_many :ticket_buyers, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name_of_event, presence: true, length: {maximum: 40}
    validates :description_tag_line, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}
    validates :description, presence: true, length: {maximum: 300}
    validates :date, presence: true
    validates :time, presence: true
    validates :location, presence: true, length: {maximum: 40}
    validates :ticket_price, presence: true, length: {maximum: 5}
end
```

model admin.rb:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events, dependent: :destroy

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

views events index.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Events</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name of event</th>
          <th>Description tag line</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Ticket price</th>
        <th colspan="7"></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  <% @events.each do |event| %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
      <td><%= event.name_of_event %></td>
      <td><%= event.description_tag_line %></td>
      <td><%= event.description %></td>
      <td><%= event.date %></td>
      <td><%= event.time %></td>
      <td><%= event.location %></td>
      <td><%= event.ticket_price %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', event_path(event) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', event_path(event),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<%= link_to 'New event', new_event_path %>
```

Comment: Here is my schema.rb.  I do have an Admin_id.  Should it be admin_id instead of Admin_id?  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
    t.string   "name_of_event"
    t.string   "description_tag_line"
    t.string   "description"
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.string   "location"
    t.decimal  "ticket_price"
    t.integer  "Admin_id"
  end

  add_index "events", ["Admin_id"], name: "index_events_on_Admin_id"

Comment: For some reason I am not able to add code to show you.  The ctrl K is not indenting it and usually it says I have too many characters.  Should I just start a new question with the new code?  I want to show the new event controller, event/index.html.erb, event/new.html.erb, my event_form.html.erb and my schema.rb.

Comment: I made all the changes you suggested.  I'm getting the error: ActionController::ParameterMissing in EventsController#new.  The new def is: def new @event = Event.new(event_params, admin: current_admin)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're not using devise to authenticate the admin at all (e.g add `before_action :authenticate_admin!` in the `EventsController`).

As soon you do, you can use `current_admin` as the currently authenticated admin and then you need to use it in the `index` query -

```
def index
    @events = Event.where(admin: current_admin)
end
```

For more information please read Devise documentation (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried that before but now it does not return any events in events.html.erb.  I'm thinking it might be an issue in the events.html.erb file in the <% @events.each do |event| %> line.  Does it need to be modified to reference current_admin?  I have attempted various approaches but nothing I have tried has worked.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I meant the events/index.html.erb.

Comment: when you `create` an event, you should initialize the `admin` attribute also. e.g `@event = Event.new(event_params, admin: current_admin)`. Moreover - you need to reference the `current_admin` in almost all functions in your controller - to verify that one can only access/create/update his own events.

Comment: Thank you.  I changed all my controllers in events/index.html.erb to include the current_admin action.  I am still not getting any events to show.  I created some new ones after I saved the changes.  One thing I noticed in my log is that I think the admin is showing nil. Here is a snipit from my log:

Comment: Started GET "/events" for ::1 at 2016-06-03 08:45:12 -0500
Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
  Admin Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Event Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."admin_id" = ?  [[nil, 1]]
  Rendered events/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 193ms (Views: 185.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Comment: I restarted my server and now when I want to create a new event I'm getting an "ActiveModel::Missing AttributeError in EventsController#new can't write unknown attribute 'admin_id'.  Shows error in app/controllers/events_controller.rb: 15:in "new'.  Here is my code in the events_controller.rb:

Comment: It looks like you don't have the reference attribute `admin_id` in the `events` table. You need to add via a migration (e.g `add_column :events, :admin_id,  :integer`).